# onPress in button gives state transition error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when trying to run remove function it gives error:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

This is the code:

```
class registrationHome extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            city: '',
            area: '',
            lat: '',
            lng: '',
            productName: '',
            products: []
        }

        this.getCoordinates = this.getCoordinates.bind(this);
        this.addProduct = this.addProduct.bind(this);
    }


    getCoordinates(){

    }

    addProduct(){
        var productsArray = this.state.products.slice();
        productsArray.push(this.state.productName);

        console.log(productsArray);
        this.setState({
            productName: '',
            products: productsArray
        });
        // console.log(this.state.products);
    }
    // remove function running recursively till stacksize exceeded
    removeProduct(index){
        var productsArray = this.state.products.splice(index,1);

        console.log(productsArray);
        this.setState({         
            products: productsArray
        });
    }

    test() {
        console.log('hey');
    }

    render() {
        // console.log(this.state.name);

        var products = this.state.products.map((product,i) => (
                            <View key={i}>
                                <Text >{product}</Text>
                                <Button
                                    title="remove"
                                    onPress={this.removeProduct(i)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        ));
        return(
            <View>              
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Business Name"
                    onChangeText={ name => this.setState({ name })}                 
                />              
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="City Name"
                    onChangeText={ city => this.setState({ city })}                 
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Area Name"
                    onChangeText={ area => this.setState({ area })}                 
                />
                <View>
                    <Text>Enter products to save</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Enter product name"
                        onChangeText={ productName => this.setState({productName})}
                        defaultValue={this.state.productName}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Add Product"
                        onPress={this.addProduct}
                    />
                    <ScrollView style={{height: 70, marginVertical: 5}}>
                        <Text>Products Entered</Text>
                        {products}
                    </ScrollView>               
                </View>

                <View>
                    <Button
                        title="Get Coordinates"
                        onPress={this.getCoordinates}                   
                    />
                    <View style={styles.coordContainer}>
                        <Text>Lat: {this.state.lat}</Text>
                        <Text>Lng: {this.state.lng}</Text>                      
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    coordContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        borderWidth: 3,
    },


})
```

Why this error is comming here and how to correct it without using listview.

can you elaborate what is happening in the above case and why removeProduct() is called infinitely till the errorstack overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `onPress` you need to pass a function like this

```
<Button
  title="remove"
  onPress={()=>this.removeProduct(i)}
 />
```

just like you are doing it in other cases.

What you want to pass is a callback function. When you use the function name with brackets like this `myFunc()`, you immediately call that function. That's why `onPress={this.removeProduct(i)}` basically says "Evaluate `this.removeProduct(i)` and use the result as a callback. This means your `removeProduct(i)` function runs during render, not when `onPress` action is performed. What you want instead is a function declaration like this `()=>this.removeProduct(i)`.

The error then is due to the fact that you invoke `setState` method inside your `removeProduct` function during `render`. Invoking `setState` during render is forbidden by React.

Comment: yeh that works.what i am passing was a function and not callback. can you elaborate what is happening in the above case and why removeProduct() is called infinitely till the errorstack  overflows.

Comment: Glad it helped!